# JS Problems : Show other select list and display value

Tags: javascript

I have 2 List (inputgol & inputmskrj).

Wanna show 2nd list (inputmskrj) based on 1st list. After that, wanna get and display value ("prices") when 2nd list selected.

The problem : 2nd list and value haven't displayed.

I tried this code, but fail. So, let me know how i missed.
Thanks.

this is my bin
`jsbin.com/wuxoxorija/edit?html,js,output`

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function nlaskes() {
        var price = document.priceCalc.inputmskrj.value;
        document.getElementById("prices").innerHTML = price;
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.menu-link').bigSlide();

            $('#inputgol').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '1a')
      {
        $("#1a").show();
        $("#1b").hide();
        $("#1c").hide();
        $("#1d").hide();
      }
      else if ( this.value == '1b')
      {
        $("#1b").show();
        $("#1a").hide();
        $("#1c").hide();
        $("#1d").hide();
      }
       else if ( this.value == '1c')
      {
        $("#1c").show();
        $("#1b").hide();
        $("#1a").hide();
        $("#1d").hide();
      }
      else 
      {
        $("#areagol").hide();
      }
    });
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
        Pilih golongan : 
        <select text-align="center" name="inputgol" id="inputgol">                    
            <option text-align="center" value="0">--Pilih golongan--</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="1a">I/A</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="1b">I/B</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="1c">I/C</option>
        </select>

    <div id="areagol">

      <div id="1a" name="1a" class="gol" style="display: none;" >
            <form name="priceCalc" action="">
            <table>
            <tr valign="middle">
            <td valign="middle"><h5><b>&nbsp;Masa kerja golongan&nbsp;:</b></h5><td>
            <td>&nbsp;
            <select text-align="center" name="inputmskrj" id="inputmskrj" class="form-control" onchange="nlaskes();" >                    
            <option text-align="center" value="0">--Pilih Masa Kerja--</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="76.693">0-5</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="83.647">6-10</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="90.107">11-15</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr >
        <tr valign="middle">
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><b>&nbsp;Nilai (Rp.)&nbsp;</b></td>
        <td align="center" ><b><h4><U><div id="prices"></div></u></h4></b></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
        </form>
        </div>

        <div id="1b" name="1b" class="gol" style="display: none;" >
            <form name="priceCalc" action="">
            <table>
            <tr valign="middle">
            <td valign="middle"><h5><b>&nbsp;Masa kerja golongan&nbsp;:</b></h5></td>
            <td>&nbsp;
            <select text-align="center" name="inputmskrj" id="inputmskrj" class="form-control" onchange="nlaskes();">                     
            <option text-align="center" value="0">--Pilih Masa Kerja--</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="76.693">0-5</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="83.647">6-10</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="90.107">11-15</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr >
        <tr valign="middle">
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><b>&nbsp;Nilai (Rp.)&nbsp;</b></td>
        <td align="center" ><b><h4><U><div id="prices"></div></u></h4></b></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
        </form>
        </div>
        <div id="1c" name="1c" class="gol" style="display: none;">
            <form name="priceCalc" action="">
            <table>
            <tr valign="middle">
            <td valign="middle"><h5><b>&nbsp;Masa kerja golongan&nbsp;:</b></h5></td>
            <td>&nbsp;
            <select text-align="center" name="inputmskrj" id="inputmskrj"                         class="form-control" onchange="nlaskes();">                     
            <option text-align="center" value="0">--Pilih Masa Kerja--</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="76.693">0-5</option>
            <option text-align="center" value="83.647">6-10</option>
            </select></td>
            </tr >
        <tr valign="middle">
        <td align="center" valign="middle"><b>&nbsp;Nilai (Rp.)&nbsp;</b></td>
        <td align="center" ><b><h4><U><div id="prices"></div></u></h4></b></td>
        </tr>
        </table> 
        </form>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the relevant code directly in the question body. And to explain what you mean when you say that code failed - do you get errors in the browser console? Or does it do *something*, but the wrong thing?

Comment: yap, edited @nnnnnn..thanks

Comment: Are you attempting to use a JavaScript library like jQuery? I don't see any included in your sample code nor the jsbin...